# Facebook Graph API page_impressions_by_city_unique weird number

Tags: facebook-graph-api

[image: page_impressions_by_city_unique weird number]

Take a look on the screenshot above, what does the weird number represent?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this also.  Seems to be a FB bug that happens intermittently.  Those numbers should be city names.  The bug seems to be temporary, but it keeps coming back.